# Borderlands 2 sanctuary slots game

Tags: borderlands-2

Is it possible to actually get 3 borderlands signs while playing slots at Moxxis bar and get an orange weapon? I'm presuming that, because if we draw the 3 legs, machine give us blue weapon and 3 marcus heads give purple weapon.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what you're asking here, please provide more details.

Comment: Agreed reword your question please.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get a orange weapon, but the possibility of that happening is extremely low. According to [this](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Slot_Machine), the possibility of getting an orange is 0.02%.